# Showing a div if all inputs are filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck trying to figure out how to show a div after checking to see if all inputs have been filled in. I am only wanting the inputs within the `#intro-info` section to be checked. I am not sure what to write in the else statement to make the button `#intro-button` display if all of the inputs have been filled in.

[Here is a fiddle if it helps](https://jsfiddle.net/mwqcsefr/1/)

```js
$(function () {   
    var intro = $('.intro');

    intro.on('keypress', function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
            $(this).next('.intro').addClass('block');
        }         
       /* else {
            $('.intro').hide();
        }*/
    });
    var allEmpty = true;

    $('#intro-info :input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            allEmpty = false;
            return false; // we've found a non-empty one, so stop iterating
        } else
    });
     return allEmpty;
});
```

```css
.intro {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.intro:first-child {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
}
.next {
  display: none;
}
#intro-button {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro-info">
  <input id="name" type="text" class="intro">
  <input id="email" type="email" class="intro">
  <input id="title" type="text" class="intro">
  <button id="intro-button">Proceed</button>
</div>



<a class="next">show div</a>
```

Comment: from your code, i feel like you want each box to appear only if above box is filled. Am i rite?

Comment: @Iceman "_to make the button #intro-button display if all of the inputs have been filled in_"

Comment: @Andreas I agree. but see this part of the code : `$(this).next('.intro').addClass('block');` mayb i was just confused.

Comment: Like this ??? -> **https://jsfiddle.net/mwqcsefr/3/**

Comment: @adeneo Yes, like that. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone see why my fadein does not work in my css when adding the block class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to set the visibility of the element.  So you can grab the input from the text fields, check their lengths, and then pass the result to this function.

For example:

```
$('.next').toggle($('#name').val().length > 0);
```

will set the visibility of the `next` div depending on whether or not something has been entered in the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `input` event instead of `keypress`
- Use `jQuery.filter` and test all the values in `form` except `button`

Also note that selector for `next` button has to be `.next`, not `#next`

```js
$(function() {
  var intro = $('.intro');
  var testFunction = function() {
    return $('#intro-info :input:not(button)').filter(function() {
      return this.value == '';
    })
  };
  intro.on('input', function() {
    $('.next').toggle(!testFunction().length);
  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  //opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.intro:first-child {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
  animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
}
.next {
  display: none;
}
#intro-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro-info">
  <input id="name" type="text" class="intro">
  <input id="email" type="email" class="intro">
  <input id="title" type="text" class="intro">
  <button id="intro-button">Proceed</button>
</div>
<a class="next">show div</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change your `keypress` to `input`.
- CSS **id selector** is prior to **class selector**, the  `#intro-button{ display:none}` is prior to `.block{display:block}`. So even though class `block` is added, but display is still none.

  The simplest solution is add `!important` in .block property `display` :

  ```
  .block {
    display: block !important;
  }
  ```
- **JS part :** Add class when all inputed.

  ```
  if (intro.filter(function(){
    return $(this).val().length > 1
  }).length === intro.length){
    $("#intro-button").addClass('block');
  }else {
    $("#intro-button").removeClass('block');
  }
  ```